# Format data with DataBinder.Eval

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, formatting

I need to convert the following line of code:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>
```

to

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id").ToString().PadLeft(3, '0') %>
```

The latter gives an exception of a malformed server tag. How can I apply methods to the DataBinder output. Please note that I already know about the following but do not want to use it:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id", "{FormatString}") %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is causing the problem is the presence of the single quotes in the padding [padLeft(3,'0')] function which is required anyway and the presence of double quote in some portion of the string... can you move the formatting to code-behind - using the databound events?

Comment: It works if you don't assign it like Text="<%# ... %>", but will work like this <asp:Label ID="xxx" runat="server"><%# ... %></asp:Label>

Comment: Crap... Did not realize the single-quote mistake for characters... Will give it a try and revert back. Thanks.

Comment: What if the Container.DataItem has a DBNULL.Value how do you get around that..? I am having issues with it in my aspx file

Answer (score 2):

i've encountered the same problem, and this is what I've done.

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id").ToString().PadLeft(3, Convert.ToChar("0")) %>
```